# Expectation of the product of dependent standard normal random variables

Tags: probability-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal random variables, and $(X,Y)$ is Gaussian, can we say anything about $E(XY)$, if we don't assume independence?

Answer (score 0):

If $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal (Gaussian), then it has the joint density $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \sigma_x \sigma_y} \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)} \left( \frac{(x - \mu_x)^2}{\sigma_x^2} - \frac{2\rho (x - \mu_x)(y - \mu_y)}{\sigma_x \sigma_y} + \frac{(y - \mu_y)^2}{\sigma_y^2} \right) \right),$$ where $(\mu_x, \mu_y)$ is the mean, and $$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_x^2 & \rho \sigma_x \sigma_y \\ \rho \sigma_x \sigma_y & \sigma_y^2 \end{bmatrix}$$ is the variance-covariance matrix.  If the marginal densities are standard normal, then $\mu_x = \mu_y = 0$ and $\sigma_x = \sigma_y = 1$, but we cannot say anything about $\rho$ except $|\rho| \le 1$.  Then the joint density becomes $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \exp \left(-\frac{x^2 - 2\rho xy + y^2}{2(1-\rho^2)} \right).$$ 
Since we know that $$\rho = \frac{\operatorname{E}[XY] - \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y]}{\sigma_x \sigma_y},$$ it is trivial to show $$\operatorname{E}[XY] = \rho.$$